# Unable to init in Vault Raft

Tags: distributed-system, hashicorp-vault, vault, raft

Installed vault in a new machine, and gave it the following config:

```
cluster_addr  = "cor-infravault101.test.ag3:8201"
api_addr      = "cor-infravault101.test.ag3:8200"
disable_mlock = true

listener "tcp" {
  address            = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  cluster_address    = "0.0.0.0:8201"
  tls_cert_file      = "/opt/vault/tls/server.crt"
  tls_key_file       = "/opt/vault/tls/server.key"
}

storage "raft" {
  path    = "/opt/vault/data"
  node_id = "1"

  retry_join {
    leader_api_addr         = "https://cor-infravault102.test.ag3:8200"
    leader_client_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/server.crt"
    leader_client_key_file  = "/opt/vault/tls/server.key"
    leader_ca_cert_file     = "/opt/vault/tls/ca.crt"
  }
  retry_join {
    leader_api_addr         = "https://cor-infravault103.test.ag3:8200"
    leader_client_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/server.crt"
    leader_client_key_file  = "/opt/vault/tls/server.key"
    leader_ca_cert_file     = "/opt/vault/tls/ca.crt"
  }
}

ui = true
```

"vault status" works fine. But when I run "vault operator init", I get the following error:

```
Error initializing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://cor-infravault101.test.ag3:8200/v1/sys/init Code: 400. Errors:

* could not start clustered storage: empty address in configuration: {Voter 1 }
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the listener really configured at 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes. Should it not be?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. Since I am using TLS, I needed to add "https" in the api_addr and cluster_addr values. So they look like this:

```
cluster_addr  = "https://cor-infravault101.test.ag3:8201" 
api_addr      = "https://cor-infravault101.test.ag3:8200" 
disable_mlock = true
```

BTW, Hashicorp documentation really SUCKS.